# The toolbar of CKEditor is not visible when the text is too long in CKEditor body

Tags: ipad, ckeditor, sencha-touch

We use CKEditor in Sencha touch framework to create a iPad app. 
When typing in the CKEditor body, the entire editor will expand and scroll down with you as you type long text in editor, but when the text is too long, the CKEditor top toolbar will be not visible. 
In actually, We want to keep the CKEditor top toolbar always visible whether the text is too long or not in CKEditor body.
Any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Daniel.

Answer (score 0):

Total shot in the dark here but when you display this in the app is the parent component allowed to scroll? Or the `layout` not `card` or `fit`?

If you are only needing to display the editor maybe `docked: 'top' or 'bottom'` could work?